# Problems while importing libjack

Tags: c++, c, audio, portaudio

I'm trying to import `portaudio.h` in my `main.cpp`. I have simple makefile :

```
EXEC = cppaudiocapture

CLIB = -I./lib/portaudio/include ./lib/portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a -lrt -lasound -ljack -pthread

$(EXEC): main.cpp
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(CLIB)

install-deps:
    mkdir -p lib
    
    curl http://files.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v19_061121.tar.gz | tar -zx -C lib
    cd lib/portaudio && ./configure && $(MAKE) -j
.PHONY: install-deps
```

When i'm trying install-deps and compile `main.cpp` I get these errors :

`make install-deps`

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib/.libs/libportaudio.so: undefined reference to `jack_port_unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/.libs/libportaudio.so: undefined reference to `jack_port_lock'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/.libs/libportaudio.so: undefined reference to `jack_port_unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/.libs/libportaudio.so: undefined reference to `jack_port_lock'
```

`make cppaudiocapture`

```
g++ -o cppaudiocapture main.cpp -I./lib/portaudio/include ./lib/portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a -lrt -lasound -ljack -pthread
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): in function `RealStop':
/home/ramen/Programming/Shazam/Shashmaqam-Finder/AudioModule/lib/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1676: undefined reference to `jack_port_unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ramen/Programming/Shazam/Shashmaqam-Finder/AudioModule/lib/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1669: undefined reference to `jack_port_lock'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ramen/Programming/Shazam/Shashmaqam-Finder/AudioModule/lib/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1688: undefined reference to `jack_port_unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ramen/Programming/Shazam/Shashmaqam-Finder/AudioModule/lib/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1681: undefined reference to `jack_port_lock'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:6: cppaudiocapture] Error 1
```

I tried installing libjack `sudo pacman -S jack jack2`, but that didn't work.